# Translate list in CakePhp

Tags: php, cakephp, translation

I am creating list in cakephp from DB like

```
$productTable = TableRegistry::get('Products');
    $containerTypes = $productTable->find('list', [
        'keyField' => 'type',
        'valueField' => 'type'
    ])
        ->group(['type']);
```

I have added in the Model of Products table

```
$this->addBehavior('Translate', ['fields' => ['type']]);
```

Like it is described in CakePhp Book 
https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/behaviors/translate.html#attaching-the-translate-behavior-to-your-tables

Doesn anybody know how can I translate list and why this method doesnt work?
Thank you

Comment: did you create the [translation table](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/behaviors/translate.html#initializing-the-i18n-database-table) and insert the translated content ?

Comment: Yes, translate works in ctp files with __('string') but I want to transle list...

Comment: Well, you have to understand that `__('string')` uses static `po` files to retrieve translations, while the `Translate` behaviour uses the `i18n` table to get translations associated to a model.